# minicom cannot write to UART on certain laptop, works on different one

Tags: serial, uart

I have connected UART according to https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/headless-raspberry-pi-setup/serial-terminal and set `enable_uart=1` and `dtoverlay=miniuart-bt` in `config.txt`.

Running the system, reading the output works correctly, but I cannot write to UART. This happens only with [`minicom`](https://salsa.debian.org/minicom-team/minicom), using latest version 2.7.1 from Debian package:

```
minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB0 -C /home/foo/minicom.log -b 115200 -c on
```

Writing works on other laptop (openSUSE, also using the latest version from package, using the same command line options). And what is strange, if I try other software (e.g. `socat`, `screen`) on Debian (machine, where `minicom` fails) writing also works. What can be wrong?

Comment: Whar are the serial port permissions? Does root connection work? Is your user a member of the 'dialout' (sometimes 'uucp') group? What does lsusb and dmesg write when you have just plugged in your adapter?

Comment: @user2497, yes, user permissions are correct (believe me, I can check it :)). Also my UART is, visible via `lsusb`. I've checked all of these, but that even was needed, because if everything works with `socat` and `screen` when using the same setup (device, speed etc), it's obvious it must be some issue with `minicom` or keyboard and chair problem :).

Comment: dmesg? lsusb? do you have that wonderful prank software 'usbguard' running?

Comment: If you believe its a problem of minicom running on a debian laptop then this is not a question belonging to Raspberry Pi. As you checked with socat and screen the RasPi is working as expected. Maybe you will get quick better answers at https://unix.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: OK, asking there. I was considering that even before. Thanks all for your input.